# How do I remove the /n from that string in the list or specify any character in the string?

Tags: python, string, list, concatenation, element

```
def stringi(file):
    doc = open(file, 'r')
    cont = doc.read()
    nums = []
    word = ""
    for i in cont:
        if i != " ":
            word += i
        else:
            nums.append(word)
            word = ""
    nums.append(word)
    doc.close()
    return nums
```

This prints `>>> ['This', 'is', 'ship', 'line', '132', '43', 'hello\n']`
from a file which has: `"This is ship line 132 43 hello"`

How do I remove the `\n` part or at least a specific character in an element?
(I'm aware that there are modules to do what I want with making each word an element but I'm a beginner and want to learn other ways.)

Comment: just write `nums.append(word.strip())`

Comment: Are you asking how to `replace` certain characters in a string?

Comment: That would also be helpful yeah. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> \n

represent here a new line character which can simply be ignored by using:

> .strip()

Beside that, you can use

> str.replace('\n', "")

Comment: Hi, thanks. Also how would i be able to remove a specific character in one of the elements by its location i.e string[1][2]

Comment: Check out the **re** package of python. You can remove all the unnecessary characters by defining the rest of the pattern will be taken care of by the "re".
If you're trying to replace something in a list you can simply apply list comprehension i.e `[num.replace('\n','') for num in nums]`